# Ceph And Subuser

Tags: cloud, storage, ceph

Can Bucket Quota and User Quota be specified for Ceph SubUser?

Bucket Quota settings did not work like normal user methods.
I used the Bucket Quota and User Quota setting method of Ceph official document.

Below Official two document.

1. https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/mgr/ceph_api/
2. https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/adminops/#modify-subuser

Answer (score 0):

It can't be. Subuser is part of User and doesn't have separate accounting of object storage operation.

Subuser exist to grant less permission to buckets then normal user. Generally it's better to create seperate users in Ceph.